# Can I load a CDN in the head markup of a community site but only on certain pages?

Tags: community, community-builder, community-cloud

I need to have a JavaScript Library CDN in the head markup of a community site but it is having a conflict with screen flows. Is there a way I can make sure the CDN is in the head markup of the site when not using the page that has a screen flow and remove it from the head markup when the user is on the page with the screen flow?

note: the CDN  has to be in the head element of the site as per their documentation...

Comment: By CDN do you mean a script/CSS being fetch from a CDN using link or script tag? Can you explain what is the conflict and what are you loading?

Comment: It is a JS library that is being fetched with a script tag, there is a conflict between the JS of the CDN and Salesforce JS. The CDN is required in the head that is why there is a conflict between the two.